# Função on do openlayers no Typescript

Tags: typescript, openlayers-3

Estou aprendendo a utilizar o openlayers juntamente com o Angular 6, porém uma das funções de evento do OL .on não é reconhecida pelo TS, tem alguma outra maneira de fazê-lo sem ser da maneira convencional?

```
this.imagery.on('postcompose', function(event: ol.render.Event){
  console.log("postcompose");
  var ctx = event.context;
  ctx.restore();
});
```

Ele aponta o erro

```
Type '(event: Event) => void' is not assignable to type '(evt: Event) => boolean'.
Types of parameters 'event' and 'evt' are incompatible.
Type 'ol.events.Event' is not assignable to type 'ol.render.Event'.
```

Se utilizo o event normalmente ele não possui a propriedade context que preciso...

Comment: Tenta `npm install --save @types/openlayers`

Comment: Já estou utilizando essa versão :/, o mapa está sendo carregado normalmente, consegui desenhar features entre outras coisa, somente essa função não funciona e n acho uma solução para isso...

Comment: Então... mas disse pra você instalar o @types/openlayers e não o openlayers... Na verdade você deve instalar os dois.

Comment: Mas o seu erro é outro de fato

Answer (score 0):

Tenta o seguinte

```
this.imagery.on('postcompose', function(event: ol.events.Event){
  console.log("postcompose");
  var ctx = event.context;
  ctx.restore();
  return true;
});
```

Comment: No primeiro momento chegou a compilar pelo menos, depois de usar por alguns momentos ele deu o mesmo erro novamente...

Comment: eu editei a resposta pq tb tem o seguinte: o `event` tem que ser do tipo `ol.events.Event` e não `ol.render.Event`, como você colocou no seu código.

Comment: Sim sim, porém precisava do context do event, aí descobri que o ol.render.Event tinha essa propriedade, para maior referência estava seguindo um exemplo do próprio OpenLayers http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/layer-spy.html?q=spy